# How to make div loop around in section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a Roulette site, but i don't have any idea how to make the divs loop around.
I need the divs to loop around when they get out of the section border.

```js
$("#right").click(function() {
  $("#one").css("left", "300px");
  $("#two").css("left", "300px");
  $("#three").css("left", "300px");
  $("#four").css("left", "300px");
  $("#five").css("left", "300px");
  $("#six").css("left", "300px");

});

$("#left").click(function() {
  $("#one").css("left", "0px");
});
```

```css
section {
  width: 80%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 5px solid gray;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 7px;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: left 2s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div#one {
  width: 15%;
  height: 50px;
  background: black;
  float: left;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0px;
  position: relative;
  transition: left 2s ease;
  loop: true;
}

div#six {
  width: 15%;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  background: red;
  float: left;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0px;
  position: relative;
  transition: left 2s ease;
  loop: true;
}

div#five {
  width: 15%;
  height: 50px;
  background: black;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0px;
  position: relative;
  transition: left 2s ease;
}

div#two {
  width: 15%;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  background: red;
  float: left;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0px;
  position: relative;
  transition: left 2s ease;
}

div#three {
  width: 15%;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  background: black;
  float: left;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0px;
  position: relative;
  transition: left 2s ease;
}

div#four {
  width: 15%;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  background: red;
  float: left;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0px;
  position: relative;
  transition: left 2s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div id="one"></div>
  <div id="two"></div>
  <div id="three"></div>
  <div id="four"></div>
  <div id="five"></div>
  <div id="six"></div>
</section>

<button id="right">
left: 100px;
</button>
```

so when i click on the button, it should move and then once they go out of the section border, the divs should loop around to the left and show again on the left.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i'll make a gif of what i want

Comment: No I got what you want. Just make a fiddle and I will correct it

Comment: wait, i get what you meant now, thanks alot for that reply! i'll just use the round rotating shape instead of what i have now.

Comment: Yea I thought if you need to make a roulette game, it would suit you better

Comment: @Smokey Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to animate all the elements, you can only animate the first one that will push the other, then you need to use overflow in order to be able to put the last element at the start.

So you may try something like this (that can be improved of course) :

```js
$("#right").click(function() {
  $('section').prepend($('section div').last().css('margin-left','-30%'));
  $('section >div').eq(1).css('margin-left', '0%');

});

$("#left").click(function() {
  $("#one").css("left", "0px");
});
```

```css
section {
  width: 80%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 5px solid gray;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 7px;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: left 2s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
}

section>div {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  margin: 0 5px;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 1s ease;
}

#one,
#three,
#five {
  background: red;
}

#two,
#four,
#six {
  background: black;
}

section>div:first-child {
  margin-left: -30%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div id="one">1</div>
  <div id="two">2</div>
  <div id="three">3</div>
  <div id="four">4</div>
  <div id="five">5</div>
  <div id="six">6</div>
</section>

<button id="right">
left: 100px;
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a class with `keyframe animation` to your jquery code, and set the pixels and time you want:

```js
$("#right").click(function() {
    $("div").addClass("animate")
})
```

```css
section {
  width: 80%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 5px solid gray;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 7px;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: left 2s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div#one {
  width: 15%;
  height: 50px;
  background: black;
  float: left;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0px;
  position: relative;
}

div#six {
  width: 15%;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  background: red;
  float: left;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0px;
  position: relative;
}

div#five {
  width: 15%;
  height: 50px;
  background: black;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0px;
  position: relative;
}

div#two {
  width: 15%;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  background: red;
  float: left;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0px;
  position: relative;
}

div#three {
  width: 15%;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  background: black;
  float: left;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0px;
  position: relative;
}

div#four {
  width: 15%;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  background: red;
  float: left;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0px;
  position: relative;
}
.animate{
  animation: roulette  7s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes roulette {
    from {left: -550px;}
    to {left: 550px;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div id="one"></div>
  <div id="two"></div>
  <div id="three"></div>
  <div id="four"></div>
  <div id="five"></div>
  <div id="six"></div>
</section>

<button id="right">
left: 100px;
</button>
```

Comment: i think this not the intended behaviore as the op said `it should move and then once they go out of the section border, the divs should loop around to the left and show again on the left.`. I think we always need to see the boxes and not disappear. So when a box reach the  end it should immediatly come at the start